# jest test cannot import cesium using create react app and craco

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, create-react-app, cesiumjs, craco

I am using create react app with craco, and craco-cesium to load cesium into my project. I am trying to setup jest to start creating tests but the issue is Cesium is using requireJS.

I added the following to my `package.json`

```
  // package.json

  ...
  "jest": {
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}', '!src/**/*.d.ts"
    ],

    "globalSetup": "<rootDir>/setupTests.js"
  }
  ...
```

based on the ticket opened up here: https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/1914

I setup the `setupTests.js` with the following code:

```
// setupTests.js
module.exports = async () => {
  var cesium = require('cesium');
  process.$Cesium = cesium
};
```

and I have the first basic test for valid rendering:

```
// App.test.js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';

it('renders without crashing', () => {
  const div = document.createElement('div');
  ReactDOM.render(<App />, div);
  ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(div);
});
```

however I get the error in one of my view inside `<App />` component with the following code:

```
import Cesium from "cesium";
...
TypeError: Cannot read property 'Ion' of undefined
...
Cesium.Ion.defaultAccessToken = '...';
```

reporting Cesium as undefined when calling it's functions. I tried to use `jest.config.js` for jest to pick up the configuration from there with the following code:

```
// jest.config.js
const { createJestConfig } = require("@craco/craco");

const cracoConfig = require("../craco.config.js");
const jestConfig = createJestConfig(cracoConfig);

module.exports = jestConfig;
```

but create react app doesn't pick up this file so I cannot try this to verify if this would work.

Answer (score 0):

encoutered the same problem. 
Upgrading `react-scripts` to version 4.0.1 and `@craco/craco@` to version 6.0.0, seemed to solve these problems, and jest now recognizes all imports from cesium. No other configuration files were needed.